# How to import testsuite to Soap UI using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui, test-runner

I am trying to automate creation of project using simple groovy script.
I have managed to create new project, import wsdl, but i am stuck with the import of testsuite.
Testsuite was exported from another project and it is in .xml file
This is what i have so far:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*  
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory

String ProjectName = "D:/work/Project/testProject.xml";
String TestWSDL = "D:/work/WSDL/AWSECommerceService.wsdl";
String tstTestSuite = "D:/work/testSuites/suite.xml";

log.info ("Path to WSDLs:");
log.info ("TestWSDL - $TestWSDL");

log.info ("Path to testSuite:");
log.info ("testsuite- $tstTestSuite");


def currentProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project;
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
WsdlInterface iface1 = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project,TestWSDL, true )[0]
//Import of testsuite should go here
project.saveAs(ProjectName);
```

Comment: Is the test suite exported has the test steps related to those wsdl which is being imported alone?

Comment: Yes it is related to those wsdls

Comment: ivanz, can you please try the solution to see if that helps?

Comment: ivanz, appreciate up vote for the helpful answer. by the way, thanks for awarding bounty.

Comment: sorry, fixed it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to be simple to use an existing test suite file into a project using `importTestSuite` method.

Here is the snippet to achieve the same.

```
project.importTestSuite(new File(tstTestSuite))
```